# Use Heap Memory in c++

Tags: c++, heap-memory

I have 3 classes,Shape is my Base Class,Rectangle and Triangle are my derived classes.

I want to store four objects from my derived classes to a Shape's pointer.

```
Shape* sh1=new Shape[4];
Rectangle aR(2,3);
Rectangle bR(4,5);
Triangle aT(2,3);
Triangle bT(4,5);

sh1[0]=&aR;
sh1[1]=&bR;
sh1[2]=&aT;
sh1[3]=&bT;
```

but i have a problem with this,
how can i fix it?

I can do this

```
Shape* sh1[4];
Rectangle aR(2,3);
Rectangle bR(4,5);
Triangle aT(2,3);
Triangle bT(4,5);

sh1+0=&aR;
sh1+1=&bR;
sh1+2=&aT;
sh1+3=&bT;
```

but why i cannot do the first way?

Comment: _`sh1[4]=&bT;`_ is UB in both cases.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You mean `Shape **sh1 = new Shape*[4];`. You want an array of pointers, not an array of shapes. If you make your `Shape` class abstract, you should get a pretty useful diagnostic, too.

Of course you shouldn't use `new` at all, and instead use a container:

```
std::vector<Shape*> sh2 = {&aR, &bR, &aT, &bT};
```

Comment: Perhaps `std::array` would be better?

Comment: ops,thansk i forget this,when i use Shape* sh1=new Shape[4] ,compiler alocate 4  blocks of Shape 's object in memory and send the address of first block to sh1 and ....

Comment: @EdHeal: Possibly - but the benefits are fairly small and I think the OP would be best served by getting a grip on how to use vector.  Then he can go back and learn about list and stack and deque and array.

Comment: @EdHeal: The "correct replacement" for array-new is `std::vector`. It's a separate question whether array-new is itself a correct design decision.

Answer (score 0):

Because variable "sh1" is a pointer to a Shape, "sh1[0]" is a Shape!

You cannot assign a pointer to a Shape to a Shape.

Therefore

```
sh1[0] = &aR
```

is wrong.

Remember that in C/C++

```
sh1[i] is equal to *(sh+i)
```

Bye